# How to prevent a product on WooCommerce from being indexed by Google?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm referring to specific product not all products. I've googled and can't find any answer to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about SEO are off topic here. You should ask this, instead, on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat.

### You can use the Robot.txt.

You can disallow a certians URLs:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
```

Or certains file type:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pdfs/ # Block the /pdfs/directory.
Disallow: *.pdf$  # Block pdf files from all bots. Albeit non-standard, it works for major search engines.
```

Or images:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/cats.jpg #Block cats.jpg image for Googlebot specifically.
```

Or Gifs:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*.gif$
```

### You can use PHP:

Paste this between `<head>` and `</head>` if you want to disallow a certain post (change "ID" with your post ID), (You have [tons of plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/custom-header/) that can help you customise the Header without need of codeing):

```
<?php if ($post->ID == X) { echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">'; } ?>
```

You can even block multiple ones using the `||` operator:

```
<?php if ($post->ID == X || $post->ID == Y) { echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">'; } ?>
```

Or you can block a certain post title:

```
<?php if(is_single('Hello World')): ?>
```

Multiple post title, always using the `||` operator:

```
<?php if ( is_single('big-announcement') || is_single('new-update-coming-soon') ) ) : ?>
```

### After you applied the change:

After you applied the change wait a few days. Then go to [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none) and check what pages are indexed and what are not indexed.

Comment: I like the PHP way. But must we put meta tag under <head> or can it be anywhere on the HTML/PHP page? Otherwise I need to edit the header.php file in WordPress theme.

Comment: @hivolih247, I added a link with plugins that could help you doing that

Answer (score 0):

there are a few solutions, maybe you'd like to use meta tags noindex. It would be something like this:

```
function product_robots_noindex_meta_tags() {
    global $product;
    $no_robots_products = array(12,13,14); // list of product ids
    if ( $product && in_array($product->get_id(), $no_robots_products) ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'product_robots_noindex_meta_tags');
```